# Use library “ggplot2” to create a visualization that shows the frequency of the tokens that appeared for at least 2000 times

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, nlp

This is my current code working on a column named "q_content".

```
*tidy_text %>% 
  count(q_content, sort = TRUE) %>% 
  filter(n > 2000) %>% 
  mutate(word = reorder(q_content, n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(q_content, n)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  xlab(NULL) + 
  coord_flip()*
```

My error:

```
*Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`.
* Column `q_content` is not found.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.*
```

Comment: Isn't the error quite specific that there is no colum `q_content`? With a generated data.frame with the column your code works.

Comment: There is a q_content column though...

Comment: Try the following line to create a dummy data object: `tidy_text = data.frame(q_content = sample(x = c("A","A","B","B","C","D","E","F"), replace = T, size = 15000))`

Comment: What is the `*` at beginning and end of your script for? And may you add the output of `dput(head(tidy_text, 100))` to your question so others can see what in the data and support you find answer better?